# Can't reach Postgres through kubernetes service

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, rancher, kubernetes-service, k3s

I'm trying to deploy postgres, but am unable to reach postgres through service, using the following domain name`testapp-postgres.default.svc.cluster.local`.

However, I get the following response

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "testapp-postgres.default.svc.cluster.local" (10.43.31.182) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The address matches the service

> default           testapp-postgres                          ClusterIP      10.43.31.182             5432/TCP                     20m

I am using the following deployment and service

```yaml
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testapp-postgres
  labels:
    app: testapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testapp
    spec:

      containers:
        - name: testapp-postgres
          image: library/postgres:12-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_NAME
                  name: testapp-secret
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_PASSWORD
                  name: testapp-secret
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: DB_USER
                  name: testapp-secret

          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/
              name: testapp-postgres-data

      volumes:
        - name: testapp-postgres-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: testapp-postgres-data

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testapp
  name: testapp-postgres
spec:
  selector:
    app: testapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
      name: postgres
```

Comment: Does your service have the right endpoints? You can check doing `kubectl describe svc testapp-postgres`

Comment: From where you are trying to access the service?

Comment: What was the solution?